# Run java event from other .js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 scripts. Separate them working perfect, one open/close menu, second recognition swipes. But how I can't open menu on swipe action/

vertical menu (show and close menu on button click)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
      isClosed = false;

    $(".hamb-button").click(function () {
      hamburger_cross();
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');      
    });

 function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });  
});
```

swipe script looking for swipe events

```
$(function() {      
  //Enable swiping...
  $(".swiper-slide").swipe({allowPageScroll:"auto"});
  $(".swiper-slide").swipe( { 
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
      //$(this).text("You swiped " + direction );
      if (direction == "left"){
          //action

          //end action              
      };
      if (direction == "right"){
          //swipe action

          //end action             
      };
    },
     threshold:200
  });
});
```

how to run hamburger_cross() when swipe founded (between //swipe action and //end action)?

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: hamburger_cross() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the hamburger cross function global:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
  overlay = $('.overlay'),
  isClosed = false;

$(".hamb-button").click(function () {
  hamburger_cross();
  $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');      
 });

 function hamburger_cross() {

  if (isClosed == true) {          
    overlay.hide();
    trigger.removeClass('is-open');
    trigger.addClass('is-closed');
    isClosed = false;
  } else {   
    overlay.show();
    trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
    trigger.addClass('is-open');
    isClosed = true;
   }
  }

 //make it global:
 window.hamburger_cross=hamburger_cross;

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });  
});
```

Now you can do

```
hamburger_cross();
```

everywhere...